# Many-to-many with private fields and type conversion in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I try to map many-to-many relation with data type conversion for private fields. I don't want public properties because I want to be able to add new `CategoryId` from Product and `ProductId` from Category but I don't want to query them from db and expose those fields outside.

```
public class Product : Aggergate
{
     private readonly List<CategoryId> _categoryIds;

     public void AddCategory(CategoryId category)
     {
          _categoryIds.Add(category);
     }
}


public class Category : Aggergate
{
     private readonly List<ProductId> _productIds;

     public void AddProduct(ProductId product)
     {
          _productIds.Add(product);
     }
}
```

note: `CategoryId` and `ProductId` encapsulated identifier like this:

```
public class CategoryId : ValueObject
{
     public int Value { get; private set; }
     public CategoryId(int value)
     {
          Value = value;

     }
}
```

I don't want to referene associative domain directly in Product and Category because I try to model entities with DDD approach.

I tried to map with `.UsingEntity(e => e.ToTable("CategoryProductTbl")` but I can't configure convensions using this approach.

I tried to create additional entity `ProductCategory` and use it for mapping only level like:

```
builder.HasMany<CategoryId>("_categoryIds")
     .WithMany("_productIds")
     .UsingEntity<ProductCategory>("ProductCategory",
     j => j.HasOne(x => x.Category)
          .WithMany("_categoryIds")
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId),
     j => j.HasOne(x => x.ProductType)
          .WithMany("_productTypesIds")
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductTypeId));
```

But I would have to add conversion for `List<CategoryId>` (it's impossible for collections afaik)

Is it possible to configure many-to-many in my example?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually want Many-to-Many, because that is used to create Navigation Property that skips the linking table, which you said you don't want.  So actually you just want to add the linking table as a regular entity without any Navigation properties of its own.

Eg

```
public class Aggregate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
internal class ProductCategory
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
public class Product : Aggregate
{
    private readonly List<ProductCategory> productCategories = new List<ProductCategory>();

    public void AddCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        productCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { CategoryId = categoryId, ProductId = this.Id});
    }
}

public class Category : Aggregate
{
    private readonly List<ProductCategory> productCategories = new List<ProductCategory>();

    public void AddProduct(int productId)
    {
        productCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { CategoryId = this.Id, ProductId = productId});
    }
}


public class Db : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Product>()
               .HasMany("productCategories")
               .WithOne();

        builder.Entity<Category>()
               .HasMany("productCategories")
               .WithOne();

        builder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
               .HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId, c.CategoryId });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;database=efCore6Test;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true", o => o.UseRelationalNulls(true))
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to create field of List<ProductCategory> type beause it breaks the rule "reference other aggregates by identity". Beside that it's not an entity or aggregate, it's just an infrastructure entity leaking into domain

Comment: ProductCategory is not an aggregate.  Its a weak entity (notice that it doesn't have its own ID) and it only exists to hold the references to the other aggregates.  And it's encapsulated inside the aggregates.  Also you need to realize that there are no "rules" only "guidelines".  At the end of the day you need to just get stuff done.